# A smooth function $f$, defined on an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, can be written the sum of $n$ smooth functions with a certain property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-topology

Let $f: B \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function on an open ball $B := B_r(a) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that there exist $C^\infty$ functions $g_1, ..., g_n: B \to \mathbb{R}$ with

(1) $f(x) = f(a) + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - a_i)g_i(x)$ for all $x \in B$,

(2) $g_i(a) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)$.

I must admit that I haven't come too far myself. My idea is to look at $f$ at the path $\{a + t(x - a): t \in [0, 1]\}$, and then somehow decompose it into it's coordinates show the existence (or concretely define) the $g_i's$, and then show that they also satisfy (2)? I had difficulties in concretely doing that, though.

Also, it's relatively abstract to imagine what I'm working with here, as I know nothing about how $f$ looks like, other than that it's smooth. Is there maybe any intuition to these $g_i's$ or to this exercise in general that makes it somewhat easier?

Comment: $f(a+h) = f(a)+ \nabla f \ . \  h  + \mathcal{O}(\|h\|^2)$

Comment: so  you get that $\displaystyle g(x) =  \frac{ f(x) - f(a) }{ \nabla f . (x-a) } = \frac{\mathcal{O}(\|x-a\|^2)}{ \nabla f . (x-a) }$  is smooth at $x=a$ and  $f(x) - f(a)  = g(x) (\nabla f . (x-a))$ and we can choose $g_i(x) = g(x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(t) = f(a+ t(x-a)), t \in [0,1].$ Then

$$g(1) - g(0) = \int_0^1 g'(t)\, dt = \int_0^1 \nabla f (a+t(x-a))\cdot (x-a)\, dt $$ $$= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^{n} D_kf(a+t(x-a))(x_k-a_k)\, dt = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k-a_k)\left(\int_0^1  D_k f(a+t(x-a)\, dt\right ).$$

Setting $g_k(x) = \int_0^1  D_k f(a+t(x-a))\, dt,$ we have the result. Just check that each $g_k \in C^\infty$ by differentiation through the integral sign.